My alfresco container appears to be in function, but i cant access it via another web browser
I can't access alfresco, more precisely the share URL, with my web browser.
I have all of the requirements for docker, docker-compose and docker-compose.yml (and i reinstalled them at least 50 times. but it doesn't see the URL.
I tried to change the firewall rules in my GCP but nothing works
I tried to reinstall the three docs I mentioned above a couple of times, nothing.
my alfresco is running, as i write, and is saying that the test is a success, but my URL doesn't work.
I tried to change my .yml files a couple of times, but it doesn't work either.
And I pinged my external ip adress in my terminal, It pings back, but when I tried the complete URL,  on port 8080, which i allowed in my firewall rules, nothing.
alfresco-1            | 2024-04-01T22:22:17,931 [] INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] Using database URL 'jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/alfresco' with user 'alfresco'.
alfresco-1            | 2024-04-01T22:22:17,931 [] INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] Connected to database PostgreSQL version 14.4 (Debian 14.4-1.pgdg110+1)
alfresco-1            | 2024-04-01T22:22:17,932 [] INFO  [api.probes.ProbeEntityResource] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] readyProbe: Success - Tested


As mentioned in your post "I tried to reinstall the three docs I mentioned above a couple of times, nothing."  Can you share the docs you followed ?

You post log from Alfresco ACS not Alfresco Share container. Look exactly on Share container and its logs with ports.

You need to check the following:
Check the port used of the container on the docker by running the command docker ps -a
Verify listening port inside the virtual machine by running command netstat -tulpn and do a telnet <Public-IP\> -p 8080
If it fails, go back on your firewall rule if it allows ingress traffic, set it to 0.0.0.0/0 to allow all traffic for troubleshooting purposes
I tried to run as per docs instrtuctions using this github repo
